# How can I update all fields (cross-reference) with OpenXML in C#?

Tags: c#, ms-word, openxml, openxml-sdk

In Word there is an option "Update field(s)".
I want to load a Word-Template and fill the FormFields with some data.
There are also fields which are references to other fields.

With Interop I can simply write "UpdateAllFields", but what's the equivalent in OpenXML?

Thank you :)

Comment: Are you asking for the Open XML, or for the Open XML SDK? Note that there's a way to mark the document such that Word will force a field update *and query the user about it* (for security reasons). But there's no way to force field updates when working in the Open XML, directly. Field updating requires the Word application (or Word Automation Services on SharePoint).

Comment: I am asking for the Open XML SDK. How does that document marking work?

Answer (score 6):

You want to use the [Open XML SDK](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5124) to update fields,right? Here’s some sample code:

```
using (WordprocessingDocument document = WordprocessingDocument.Open(path, true))
{
  DocumentSettingsPart settingsPart = document.MainDocumentPart.GetPartsOfType<DocumentSettingsPart>().First();
  // Create object to update fields on open
  UpdateFieldsOnOpen updateFields = new UpdateFieldsOnOpen();
  updateFields.Val = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.OnOffValue(true);
  // Insert object into settings part.
  settingsPart.Settings.PrependChild<UpdateFieldsOnOpen>(updateFields);
  settingsPart.Settings.Save();
}
```

For more information, please refer the link below:

[OpenXML: How to refresh a field when the document is opened](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfedev/2010/08/08/openxml-how-to-refresh-a-field-when-the-document-is-opened/)

Comment: This URL is now 404. :-(

Comment: Maybe it's the same as this?  http://www.samuraiprogrammer.com/blog/2010/08/09/OpenXMLHowToRefreshAFieldWhenTheDocumentIsOpened.aspx